# passing ctrl+z to pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

How do I pass a certain key combination to a spawned/child process using the pexpect module? I'm using telnet and have to pass Ctrl+Z to a remote server.

Tnx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [sendcontrol()](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html#spawn-sendcontrol)

for example:

```
p = pexpect.spawn(your_cmd_here)
p.sendcontrol('z')
```